# If connected to FTP server do something, else do other something

Tags: java, ftp

So I'm trying to do something like:

```
If connected
   do something on ftp files;
else
   do something on local files;
```

I tried to do this in that way:

```
public boolean checkConnection() {
    boolean answer = client.isConnected();
    if (answer) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

if (ftpConnection.checkConnection()) {
    System.out.println("Connected!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not connected.");
}
```

And when I'm using version where I'm connectiong to FTP Server I have "Connected". But when I run other version, I have RuntimeException. Somebody have maybe idea how can I solve my problem?

Comment: what means *when I run other version*?? can you post your `RuntimeException`?

Comment: When I run version where "ftpConnection = null" I have "java.lang.NullPointerException" instead of "not connected".

Comment: `ftpConnection = null` will set `ftpConnection` to `null`, to `NullPointerException` is totally normal

Comment: What is `client`? What are you expecting `isConnected()` to tell you? What is `ftpConnection`. What are you expecting `checkConnection()` to tell you? What is 'other version'? What exactly does. 'I have `RuntimeException`' mean? What's the *question*?

Answer (score 0):

For me it sounds like your client returns the RunTimeException when it can't connect to the server, so maybe you add a try/catch block and if the exception is thrown, check if the exception says "can't connect" and return false

Answer (score 0):

You could use the State design pattern, with a different state object for connected and unconnected states. Something like this:

```
 interface ConnectionState {
    public void doStuff();
 }

 private final ConnectionState FTP_CONNECTION_STATE = new ConnectionState() {
    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
       ... // do something on FTP files
    }
 };

 private final ConnectionState LOCAL_CONNECTION_STATE = new ConnectionState() {
    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
       ... // do something on local files
    }
 };

 private ConnectionState connectionState;

 public final void tryToConnect() {
    ....
    if (connected) {
       connectionState = FTP_CONNECTION_STATE;
    } else {
       connectionState = LOCAL_CONNECTION_STATE;
    }
 }

 public final void doStuff() {
    if (connectionState == null) {
       throw new IllegalStateException("tryToConnect() has not been called");
    }
    connectionState.doStuff();
 }
```